# ¿Response sin ModelSerializer en Django?

Tags: python, sql, json, django, djangorestframework

Necesito enviar la lista "busqueda" por response, el problema es que no logro serializarla con la libreria "JSON" que trae django por defecto y enviarla por la URL al Frontend, ¿Como puedo serializar la lista y enviarla como cualquier objeto json al frontend con response?
Este es el view:

```
class FindValue(APIView):
def post(self, request):
    value_json = json.loads(request.body.decode("utf-8"))
    productos_similares = Product.objects.filter(name_product__icontains=value_json[0]["value"])
    categorias_similares = Category.objects.filter(name_category__icontains=value_json[0]["value"])
    busqueda = []
    for prod in productos_similares:
        busqueda.append(prod)
    for cat in categorias_similares:
        busqueda.append(cat)
    return Response(busqueda, status=200)
```

El error en consola se resume en:

```
return super(JSONEncoder, self).default(obj) File "C:\Python27\lib\json\encoder.py", line 184, in default
raise TypeError(repr(o) + " is not JSON serializable")
```

TypeError:  is not JSON serializable

Comment: no entiendo por que quieres serializar el request en vez de serializar el resultado de la busqueda

Comment: en realidad el request lo serializo para poder trabajar con el en la consulta sql del objeto object.filter, sin embargo la que no logro serializar ni de esa manera es el resultado de las busquedas, mas exactamente el array busqueda

Comment: podrias revisar esto: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7650448/django-serialize-queryset-values-into-json